# Query: Select distinct row in laravel

Tags: laravel, select, query-builder, distinct-values

It's me again...
I have a table agendas and in this table I have columns employe, hrbp and direction.

How can I get the list of direction where hrbp is HRBP1

```
 $ListDirectionHRBP1 = DB::table('agendas')->select('direction')->where('hrbp','=','HRBP1')->distinct()->get();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$ListDirectionHRBP1 = DB::table('agendas')->where('hrbp','=','HRBP1')->select('direction')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. But i get a direction several times in the query. I want to have it on time in the list

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this :-

```
$ListDirectionHRBP1 = DB::table('agendas')->where('hrbp','=','HRBP1')->select('direction')->get()->toArray();
```